# DataGridViewRow.Tag was null in TabControl. Is this a bug?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 1 TabControl, this TabControl have 2 Tab are TabPage1 and TabPage2.

TabPage1 have DataGridView1, TabPage2 have DataGridView2.

I use DataGridViewRow.Tag property to save object when load data from database.

The problem is only DataGridView1 in TabPage1 saved object to Tag, DataGridView2 in TabPage2 is not.

I have try load data for GridViewTab2 before load data for GridViewTab1 but nothing change.

I found a way to fix it: I changed TabControl.SelectedIndex = 1 before load data for DataGridView2. And it work ok. You can see it in my screenshot.

But I want to know why? Sorry for my English.

```
        //dataGridView1 in tabControl1.TabPages[0]
        dataGridView1.DataSource = DataProvider.GetPersons();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            Person p = new Person();
            p.name = row.Cells["name"].Value.ToString();
            p.old = (int)row.Cells["old"].Value;
            p.address = row.Cells["address"].Value.ToString();
            row.Tag = p;    //Add person object to current row.tag
        }

        //If not have row BELOW (*), dataGridView2 row.tag will be null.
        tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1;  //(*)

        //So I want tabControl1.SelectedTab is the first tab, then I use row below to do that.
        tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0;

        //dataGridView2 in tabControl1.TabPages[1]
        dataGridView2.DataSource = DataProvider.GetBooks();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
        {
            Book b = new Book();
            b.name = row.Cells["name"].Value.ToString();
            b.author = row.Cells["author"].Value.ToString();
            b.price = (int)row.Cells["price"].Value;
            row.Tag = b;    //Add book object to current row.tag
        }
```

My Code:
[image: My code]

Comment: Now, you already have a `DataSource` that holds your objects. Why do you need to have them assigned to the `Tags` properties? You can get an object of a selected row through the data source.

Comment: This is caused by the TabControl operation (you wouldn't like all controls in all tab pages initialized right away. See the Remarks section of the [TabPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tabpage) Class). But, as alredy mentioned in the previous comment, you already have these informations in the DataGridView and you also can use the DGV's DataSource property to access a record, if/when needed. You could also use a BindingSource to bind the Data(Table?) to the DGV and use the CurrencyManager to manage the *current* record.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, you already have bound your DataGridView to (presumably) a List of Person objects via this line:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = DataProvider.GetPersons();
```

You can retrieve the data-bound item from the selected rows in the DGV, as needed. Here is a quick "Friday evening, gotta be leaving" copy and paste VB.NET example, but should be trivial to convert to C#:

```
Dim selected As Person = DirectCast(dgvFavorites.SelectedRows(0).DataBoundItem, FavoriteDTO)
```